# Error (4800004) authorizing web app

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-console

I was debugging my app in my personal Google play services account but the company I am working on has already got their Google play services account so I changed and DELETED (deleting api credentials and unpublished it) the game. I have managed to register a new android app but when I try to register a web app I get the error #4800004 (An unexpected error has occurred. Try again later).
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It can take approx 7 days for your old package to be removed. You will not be able to add a new one until that happens.

Your options:

- Wait 7 days and try again.
- Rename your package.

Alternately: You cannot have two apps with the same package details. Are your two apps conflicting with each other?

Comment: I've change the package name but it doesn't work. As i said in the answer below i can't create any web app even if they are in differents Play Services.

Answer (score 1):

From the [github post](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/189), it was mentioned that you maybe re-registering an app with the same package name. You can check if your project was already registered in the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Projects that you have deleted will take effect after the 7th day.

For further information, you can also try to check [this page](https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/tag/an-unexpected-error-occurred-please-try-again-later-4800004/). It may also have something to do with SHA1 Signing Certificate Fingerprint from android studio.

Comment: Yes, i've changed the package name without success. It's weird because I can't create a WEB LINKED APP in any Play Services i've created (even that they are totally different in package name and content).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the LaunchURL that you provide includes the protocol (for example: http://) in addition to the domain. If you do not provide the protocol, google appears to automatically add https://, but this led to the error posted in the question for me.